# Prove that this graph doesn't exist

Tags: graph-theory

A group of 3141 students gather together. Some of them have 13 friends in this group, some have 33 friends, and the rest has 37 friends. Prove using graph theory that this group does not exist. Assume that if A is friends with B, then B is friends with A.

Comment: Meta-question: Why start with the digits of $\pi$ and then veer off to $13$, $33$, $37$? (Could it be a le(ee)et-speak in-joke?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like homework; so, let me just give you a hint.

Say that you have $a$ people with 13 friends, $b$ with 33, and the remaining $3141-a-b$ have 37.  In the graph, this corresponds to having $a$ vertices of degree 13, $b$ vertices of degree $33$, and the rest of degree 37.

So, the total degree of the graph is
$$
13a+33b+37(3141-a-b).
$$
Simplify this, and see if you can prove that no matter how you choose $a$ and $b$, the resulting total degree will always be odd.  Why is this impossible in a graph?

Comment: Thank you for this. I have figured out the problem thanks to your help and Ross's help.

Answer (score 3):

The handshaking theorem tells you that the sum of the degrees of a graph is even.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have managed to solve this :)